# Adding Mailchimp subscribe into custom theme

Tags: plugin-mailchimp

I am creating custom theme and we would to add Mailchimp subscribe form. This is somewhat easy with Mailchimp for Wordpress plugin, but this plugin creates forms with certain ID and there is no possibility for us to pre-determine which form ID will this plugin create so when user installs the theme they will have to change form ID in the actual code and we would like to avoid this. So my question is how to create forms that can work with default theme installation requiring only adding Mailchimp api credentials (API key and List ID) into customizer.

Comment: This is a general question and sounds like you didn't research very much. Please provide some code, nobody is going to give you the finished project.

Comment: Thanks. I am not looking for completed code just a guideline from someone that had experience with it.

Comment: Well, you need to add a setup page or something like that in your theme, then add a form to it in which the user can enter the id of the list. Theeen grab that id from the settings form and output it into your theme frontend.

Comment: Thank will try to set something up.

Comment: hello i have the same question and i made somme researshes and found a tutorial i think it will help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4WsX1uzdRc&ab_channel=GyanNiti